# Inside the Discussion Board list the number of Likes for an item is not equal to the popup which show who like an item

Tags: 2013, development, discussion-board, like

I am working on an on-premises farm 2013. and inside a team site i added a new Discussion Board list. now i checked a discussion item which have 26 like count, and this discussion item does not have any reply. so i hover over the Like count, but the popup is showing only 21 users, as follow:-

[image]

so i am confused on what could be causing this issue? as the popup should show 26 users and not only 21 !!

now i checked the web and seems inside sharepoint on-premises 2013 , there is a bug that when someone unlike a discussion item, the Like count will not get decreased as mentioned in this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2211c35a-ade8-4f7c-8684-c0170f34c7ab/discussion-board-likes-count-not-decrease-after-clikcing-unlike?forum=sharepointgeneral) .. so now i am left with these two possibilities of what could be causing this issue:-

1- Either the popup dialog, only show maximum of 21 users?

2- or there are 5 users (26 - 21 = 5 users) who like the item, but later on they chose to unlike it.. so the above bug could cause this inconsistency between the number of Likes and the number of users inside the popup windows??..

second question. can i view all the users who liked an item inside a separate view? as currently the popup will disappear after a couple of seconds.. and in our case liking an article have a business impact that the user confirm that he have read the discussion item. but showing the users inside a popup is a headache is you need to know exactly the users who like it..
Thanks